# Why is rsync 2x faster than sftp?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sftp, transfer, scp

I'm transferring huge files, over a network to a destination server, totaling ~ 67 GB with individual zip files of size ~ 7GB. I tried copying to the destination using both `sftp` and `rsync`. `rsync` performs (2x) faster copying than `sftp`. `sftp` was achieving around **700 kbps** while `rsync` transfers the data at a rate north of **1.4 Mbps**. I know that SFTP and SCP uses the same SSH connection for transferring files. So, does this imply `rsync` is much (2x) faster than SCP which uses SSH under the hood?

Or above all, is there an even faster way to transfer (such huge) files over a network?

P.S.: I'm transferring completely new data to the destination server with the following `rsync` command:

```
rsync --info=progress2 -az source_folder username@destination_server:/location/
```

Comment: Is rsync connecting using SSH? Are you just updating data or is this transferring entirely new data? What options did you use for rsync?

Comment: @muru please see my updated question!

Comment: So you're using compression `-z`. Try without it.

Comment: @muru On average, the transfer speed is same whether I use compression `-z` or not :(

Comment: Do you mean `sftp` or `scp`? `scp` is known to be slower because it requires more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

> Or above all, is there an even faster way to transfer (such huge) files over a network?

You can speed up scp with

```
scp -p -C -o 'CompressionLevel 9' -o 'IPQoS throughput'  -c arcfour machine:file .
```

I saw up to 5 times better speed using scp but of course external factors play a big role here.

Comment: I'm getting `command-line line 0: Unsupported option "compressionlevel"` and `Unknown cipher type 'arcfour'` errors while trying your suggestion

Comment: Also, I found exactly same answer here: https://superuser.com/a/787479 . Not whether this answer was copied from this link